# Get rid of evil's state info such as ` -- INSERT -- ` in the echo area

Tags: evil

How can I get rid of the state information of evil in the echo area? I've already displayed it in the status bar and there is no need to occupy the echo area.

Comment: FWIW, it does *not* occupy the echo area as it's gone by the next time a command prints something.

Comment: @wasamasa Yes, but it freshes away the message I currently have...

Comment: How about commenting out line 112 of `evil-states.el` (current version as of 12/07/2016) -- i.e., comment out:  `:message "-- INSERT --"` and if necessary `byte-compile-file` after it has been modified?  Here is a link to the exact line of the source code:  https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/src/f2648b841f9bcded8764ce63410065d2b8c5f856/evil-states.el?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#evil-states.el-112

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution for insert state. You can apply the same idea to other states as you see fit.

```
(setq evil-insert-state-message nil)
```